# RDP Not Working Properly Remotely Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I run a Windows 2012 server, I am having some issues using RDP. Up until a few days ago it was working perfectly from outside my network,however now it won't work. To be more specific it logs me in and shows me the desktop, however I can't click on anything or type at all or anything like that. A few minutes later it will give me a socket error(Failed To Read From Socket: -1). I have tried connecting form Macs and Windows computers and the result is the same.

I've checked my router settings to make sure that the right port is forwarded, firewall settings haven't been changed, and I checked the registry. As I said it was working fine a few days ago so not surprisingly all the settings were still correct.

Does anyone know what may be wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**

The issue has gone away, I deleted the Optimize Start Menu Cache Files task and it now seems to be working fine. I'm not entirely sure if deleting that task helped at all but its working now.

Comment: Can you RDP to it successfully from a computer within the same LAN?  Are there any related errors reported in the Server's event logs? Have you tried rebooting the server?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly on LAN, but not otherwise. The only log I come across says:
The RemoteFX encoding engine encountered an error (0x8007007A).
Lol of course I've tried rebooting the server, looking for updates, installing those updates, but still nothing.